# how to get those array values randomly?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following string array:

```
String arry[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
            "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
            "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
            "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^",
            "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", ";", ":", "'", "|", "",
            "<", ",", ">", ".", "/", "?", };
```

In this String array how to get a values randomly ?

For example:

```
AG.4fF
h9_wO4
```

So far, I have the following code:

```
for (String st : arry) {
    String randomValue = arry[new Random().nextInt(arry.length)];
    System.out.println(" Inside array  values :-->> " + randomValue);

}
```

For this code, it returns all the array values, then how to form a multiple combinations.

as i mentioned earlier?

Comment: By writing code that gets values randomly.

Comment: What have you attempted? If you don't know where to start, I'd suggest checking the API for [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Or maybe even [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

Comment: As some other users have stated, you can use the `Random` API that Java ships with and make sure it falls within the range of your array `arry`

Comment: +1, now your question is well-asked. Voting to repoen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a String of characters you can do

```
static final String chars = 
               "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
               "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
               "0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_" +
               "=+;:'|\"<,>./?";

static final Random rand = new Random();
public static String randString(int length) {
     char[] gen = new char[length];
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
          gen[i] = chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length));
     return new String(gen);
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter Lawrey, thanks for your code, i worked in above code ,its working fine ..

Comment: @ShivaShankar Hi Shiva Shankar.

Comment: It generate more than 100 characters i take from 0 t0 7 only , is this right way to do that or any specific format for taking multiple combinations of character .

Comment: It generates the length you ask it to generate. If you do `randString(7)` it will generate a length of 7.

Comment: Yes absolutely ,it working fine .Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean generating random string from this set of characters? You can perform it in this way:

```
int len = ...; // length of resulting string
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    String c = arry[rand.nextInt() % arry.length];
    builder.append(c);
}
String str = builder.toString();
```

Comment: While your answer might be correct, it doesn't really help OP because it gives him a ready solution to use, even without understanding it (See above deleted answer). Please, we don't want to encourage questions that doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this code won't compile since the elements in `arry` are Strings, not chars. You might want to fix the declaration for `c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random;

...

Random random = new Random(); // Step 1 - creating random object
System.out.println(arry[random.nextInt(arry.length)]); // Step 2
```

In step 2. we generate random number within range of 0 to arrays length than get element reside

Random.nextInt(int n) method returns pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Comment: When posting answers, please add and explanation describing what you changed or added or how it works or something. Even though your answer may be the solution, it's likely that some people who read this don't understand what it means or how it works.